# Platonic graphs in spaces having genus > 0

Tags: general-topology, geometry, graph-theory, soft-question

In the book "Introduction to Graph Theory", Richard J Trudeau dedicates a chapter on g-platonic graphs (platonic graphs in topological spaces with genus > 0).
My question is, what are those platonic graphs? In the book Trudeau makes examples of just the case with g=1. In particular I'm looking for resources, maybe an archive where such graphs are stored. I thank in advance the graph theorists who are going to answer.

I'm not sure whether I can post content from the book but this is an illustration of a platonic graph in S1 found at the end of the chapter.
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you looking for as an answer? I doubt that there is an "archive" of such graphs anywhere.

Comment: @MishaLavrov just any information really, a pdf file or a paper illustrating such graphs